# Sed replace variable in double quotes

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I've created a bash script that takes a parameter. I want to pass that parameter to sed to replace an existing string with another which is composed of the variable:

```
variable=$1
echo $variable
sed -i -e 's/name="master"/name="$variable"/g' test
```

The problem is that the script is not replacing $variable with the parameter, it's just replacing the string with "$variable":

```
<host name=""$variable"" xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:3:0:>
```

**How can I replace a string in quotes with the variable?**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Variable expansion does not happen within single quotes.  Do it in double quotes:

```
sed -i -e 's/name="master"/name="'"$variable"'"/g' test
```

Comment: Beware, though, that you'll need to escape characters interpreted specially by `sed` (such as `/`) in the value of `variable`.

Answer (score 3):

Change your code like his,

```
sed -i -e 's/name="master"/name="'"$variable"'"/g' test
```

Answer (score -3):

just do like this:

```
var=apple
sed -i "s/pineapple/$"
```

Comment: Am I to presume that you've actually tried that code?  Are we to just ignore the fact that you didn't provide a filename for `-i` nor a syntactically valid sed command?