# Linux Replace With Variable Containing Double Quotes

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

I have read the following:

- [How Do I Use Variables In A Sed Command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76808/how-do-i-use-variables-in-a-sed-command/76842)
- [How can I use variables when doing a sed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69112/how-can-i-use-variables-when-doing-a-sed)
- [Sed replace variable in double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707923/sed-replace-variable-in-double-quotes)

I have learned that I can use `sed "s/STRING/$var1/g"` to replace a string with the contents of a variable. However, I'm having a hard time finding out how to replace with a variable that contains double quotes, brackets and exclamation marks.

Then, hoping to escape the quotes, I tried piping my result though `sed 's/\"/\\\"/g'` which gave me another error `sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unknown command: E'`. I was hoping to escape the problematic characters and then do the variable replacement: `sed "s/STRING/$var1/g"`. But I couldn't get that far either.

I figured you guys might know a better way to replace a string with a variable that contains quotes.

File1.txt:

```
Example test here
<tag>"Hello! [world]" This line sucks!</tag>
End example file
```

Variable:

```
var1=$(cat file1.txt)
```

Example:

```
echo "STRING" | sed "s/STRING/$var1/g"
```

Desired output:

```
Example test here
<tag>"Hello! [world]" This line sucks!</tag>
End example file
```

Comment: `sed` is the not the right tool for this substitution.

Comment: @anubhava I see. Thanks for the advice Anubhava. I'm open to anything that works. Will try doing more research too. Editing the question to reflect that.

Comment: @batMan yea, that's the idea. To keep the data in the variable the same. I want to substitute for `STRING` with the contents of `$var1`. That's where I'm stuck. This is just a minimalist example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using **awk**

```
$ echo "STRING" | awk -v var="$var1" '{ gsub(/STRING/,var,$0); print $0}'
Example test here
<tag>"Hello! [world]" This line sucks!</tag>
End example file
```

`-v var="$var1"`: To use shell variable in awk
`gsub(/STRING/,var,$0)` : To globally substitute all occurances of "STRING" in whole record `$0` with `var`

**Special case** : "If your `var` has `&` in it " say at the beginning of the line then it will create problems with `gsub` as `&` has a special meaning and refers to the matched text instead.

To deal with this situation we've to escape `&` as follows :

```
$ echo "STRING" | awk -v var="$var1" '{ gsub(/&/,"\\\\&",var); gsub(/STRING/,var,$0);print $0}'
&Example test here
<tag>"Hello! [world]" This line sucks!</tag>
End example file
```

Comment: Thank you @batMan. This works for me. You're my hero.

Comment: @DomainsFeatured: :)

Comment: In many cases this won't work. .e.g. if `$var1` contains `&` character anywhere.

Comment: Better but if `File1.txt` has a backslash e.g. `a\m` then it will output just `am` not `a\m`

Comment: @anubhava: Yes makes sense. Do you know about other cases as well which should be handled ?

Comment: To handle all kind of special characters properly better to avoid `gsub` since it uses a regex. Use pure string based functions such as `index`, `substr` etc.

Comment: @anubhava: But it's not about just `gsub`. If the variable has say `\\` then during awk runtime it will be escaped and will lose its meaning until and unless this is handled at the source level.

Comment: @EdMorton: Hi Ed. Any suggestion for handling special characters in such casess. Is escaping at source file/var level the best possible solution ?

Comment: @batMan: Posted an answer to demonstrate what I was saying in comments. It is bit more verbose as there is no builtin function in `awk` for non-regex replacement.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't the quotes. You're missing the "s" command, leading `sed` to treat `/STRING/` as a line address, and the value of `$var1` as a command to execute on matching lines. Also, `$var1` has unescaped newlines and a `/` character that'll cause trouble in the substitution. So add the "s", and escape the relevant characters in `$var1`:

```
var1escaped="$(echo "$var1" | sed 's@[\/&]@\\&@; $ !s/$/\\/')"
echo "STRING" | sed "s/STRING/$var1escaped/"
```

...but realistically, @batMan's answer (using `awk`) is probably a better solution.

Comment: Ooops. I was running it with the "s" but it wasn't working either. Your answer does work! It's nice to have the background information for learning purposes. Your skills to escape those other characters is masterful.

Comment: @Gordon-Davisson:  this is really helpful. Can you explain bit of your second part i.e `$ !s/$/\\/'`

Comment: @batMan That part escapes the newlines *except* the one at the end of the file (/string). Frankly, it's rather messy. `echo` adds a newline to the end of the variable as it prints it; in `sed`, the `$ !` address applies to all but the last line of the file, and `s/$/\\/` adds a backslash at the end of the line (the backslash is doubled because it has to be escaped itself...). Note that `$` is playing two different roles here -- in the line address it matches the last line; in the substitute pattern it matches the end of the line. Then after all that's done, `$( )` removes the last newline.

Comment: Yes, escape and meaning of `$` inside sed was clear to me. I've now understood the use of `$ !` in this regard. Thank Gordon. That was indeed helpful. Quite nicely explained.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one awk command that gets text-to-be-replaces from a file that may consist of all kind of special characters such as `&` or `\` etc:

```
awk -v pat="STRING" 'ARGV[1] == FILENAME {
   # read replacement text from first file in arguments
   a = (a == "" ? "" : a RS) $0
   next
}
{
   # now run a loop using index function and use substr to get the replacements 
   s = ""
   while( p = index($0, pat) ) {
      s = s substr($0, 1, p-1) a
      $0 = substr($0, p+length(pat))
   }
   $0 = s $0
} 1' File1.txt <(echo "STRING")
```

To be able to handle all kind of special characters properly this command avoids any regex based functions. We use plain text based functions such as `index`, `substr` etc.

Comment: That's a lot! But, very useful! Thanks @Anubhava :-)